# Find the matrix representation (call it $M$) of $T$ relative to the basis $E$ for $V$

Tags: matrices

In this problem, $V$ is the vector space of all $3 \times 2$ matrices, and the set $E = \{e1, e2, \dots, e6\}$ is a basis for $V$, where
$$E =  \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\ \right\}$$

Let $T:V->V$ be the linear transformation give by $T(X) = AX + XB$

where $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix},  \ \ B = \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 0 \\ 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$$

Use $Y = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 7 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ as example matrix.

Find the coordinate vector of $Y$ relative to basis $E$.
Find the matrix representation (call it $M$) of $T$ relative to the basis $E$ for $V$
Find a matrix $W$ for which $T(W) = 5W$

Comment: So what's $T(e_1)$ then?

Comment: T(e1) would be {{6,0}, {0,0}, {1,0}}

Comment: So $T(e_1)=6 e_1+0 e_2+ 1 e_3+ 0 e_4 +0 e_5 +0 e_6$, so now you've got the first column of the matrix of $T$.